# Stream aggregation in the execution plan with distinct clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i am using distinct clause in a query and after switching to execution plan it is showing 93% cost to clustered index scan and 7% to stream aggregate.

My query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT LastName
FROM Person.Person
```

Can someone explain that? And one more thing i am new to this execution plan thing and i want to understand each and everything associated in execution plan so is there any blog or book that will help me understand execution plan. 
Thanks

Comment: Start with the database documentation on the execution plans.

Comment: distinct is internally implemented as group by ,so any group by operators features stream aggregate /hash aggregate depending on query

Answer (score 2):

### DISTINCT

The `DISTINCT` keyword uses an internal `GROUP BY`

> A DISTINCT and GROUP BY usually generate the same query plan, so
>   performance should be the same across both query constructs.

http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/distinct-vs-group

### Stream Aggregate

> The Stream Aggregate operator groups rows by one or more columns and
>   then calculates one or more aggregate expressions returned by the
>   query.

[Stream Aggregate Showplan Operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189907(v=sql.105).aspx)

#### More References

You will find here the exhaustive [logical and physical operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191158(v=sql.105).aspx)